# Is there a way to refresh the browser page every 15 mins if it has been idle for 15 mins using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
intervalID = setInterval(() => window.location.reload(true), 15000 );
```

---

I have tried above logic it is working fine but i need a logic in reactjs that refresh window page when user is idle

---

Comment: it should be the same, nothing will be different since react is javascript framework.

Comment: you can write something in plain js. Attach event listeners to keypress, mousemove, touch etc on document. keep a counter. When one these events happens, it means the user is interacting. If not, after 15 mins from the last inteeraction refresh this page. This has nothing to do with reactjs though.

Comment: You probably don't want *that* callback on an interval, but rather on a timeout that is reset anytime a user interacts with the page. It's up to you to determine what interactions (or lack thereof) define "being idle". I.e. if I'm casually reading and fidgeting with the mouse or scrolling a bit, am I idle?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using class based components. you could make use of event listeners for tracking the user activity as follows:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isIdle: false
    }
    this.idleTime = 0;
    this.handleTimer = this.handleTimer.bind(this);
    this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.resetTimer);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('keypress', this.resetTimer);
    this.idleInterval = setInterval(this.handleTimer, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.resetTimer);
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('keypress', this.resetTimer);
    clearInterval(this.idleInterval)
  }

  resetTimer() {
    this.idleTime = 0;
    this.setState({isIdle: false})
  }

  handleTimer() {
    this.idleTime = this.idleTime + 1;
    if (this.idleTime > 10) { 
        this.handleIdle();
    }
  }

  handleIdle() {
    // Refresh your page here
    this.setState({isIdle: true})
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      <h1 className="demo">React Template</h1>
        {this.state.isIdle && 
        <p>You have been idle for {this.idleTime} seconds</p>
        }
        </div>      
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Answer (score -1):

try below the code, edit.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const check = ()=> {
      if (!document.hasFocus()) {
          window.location.reload()
      }
    }
    setInterval(check, 1000*60*15)
  })
```

or one line.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(()=> !document.hasFocus() ? document.location.reload(): '', 1000*60*15)
  })
```

please let me know if you need this solution.